# Flask App not Routing POST Requests Correctly

Tags: python, http, flask

I have a Flask app that I'm testing on my machine with the following function:

```
@app.route('/api/v2.0/daily_task', methods=['POST'])
def create_daily_task():
    err = validate_daily_task(request)
    if err is None:
        code, dtid = mongoHelper.createNewDailyTask(request.json)
        if code == 201:
            return jsonify(dtid), 201
        else:
            abort(400)
    else:
        return jsonify(err), 400
```

When I run the following CURL request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"date":"12.12.12","notes":"","values":{"depression":0,"anxiety":0,"motivation":0,"cravings":0,"emotional_health":0,"boredom":0,"alcohol":0,"energy":0,"drug":0,"relationship":0,"physical":0,"spiritual":0,"anger":0},"id":"","owner":"5900a8799a4dc54402d090e1"}' http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v2.0/daily_task/
```

which I know passes the server's validation method, I get the following response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Consequetly, all `GET` requests work correctly, but other `POST` requests do not. Why is the app not routing my `POST` requests correctly, and how can I fix this?

Comment: `http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v2.0/daily_task/` --> `http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v2.0/daily_task` ? (remove the trailing slash from the request url)

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thank you so much!